# Can't get symlinks to work for dotfiles

Tags: bash, unix, dotfiles

So I'm trying to create symlinks for my dotfiles (that way I can have a centralized dotfiles repository) but everytime I do this, iTerm won't read the symlinked files.  Basically meaning I won't have access to any aliases or other configurations.

I believe I'm correctly symlinking the files by putting the link in the home directory and the actual file in the repository location with:

```
ln -s ~/.dot_file ~/Google\ Drive/Developer/git\ repositories/dotfiles/dot_file
```

I've also tried doing it the reverse way but then the repository doesn't have the contents of the file in the link.  aka:

```
touch ~/Google\ Drive/Developer/git\ repositories/dotfiles/dot_file
mv .dot_file ~/Google\ Drive/Developer/git\ repositories/dotfiles/dot_file
cd ~/Google\ Drive/Developer/git\ repositories/dotfiles
ln -s dot_file ~/.dot_file
```

I've referenced these articles.

- [How to use Github to manage dotfiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292409/how-to-use-github-to-manage-dotfiles)
- [Using bash to automate dotfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238019/using-bash-to-automate-dotfiles)
- [Using find on subdirectories and create symlinks to all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795538/bash-script-to-loop-through-subdirectories-and-create-symlinks-to-all-files)
- [Symlinks not working when link is made in another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601988/symlinks-not-working-when-link-is-made-in-another-directory)

Help please! :)

Comment: Just to be on the same page, `ln -s REAL_FILE LINK`, that's the parameter order, you seem to have it reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example links the wrong way (it's `ln -s source target`, just like `cp` and `mv`).

In your second example, you create an invalid relative link.

You can use `ls -l yourfile` to see whether a file is a symlink, and see where it points.

What you'll want to do is:

```
cd ~ 
ln -s "Google Drive/Developer/git repositories/dotfiles/dot_file" ".dot_file"
```

Before you start, make sure you don't have a `~/.dot_file`, and make sure your `Google Drive/Developer/git repositories/dotfiles/dot_file` is a regular file with the contents you want (again, with `ls -l`).

Comment: I seriously want to shake your hand right now.  Spent way too long trying to figure this stupid thing out.